# Using sponge to read and write to the same file with sed results in an empty file

Tags: sed, moreutils

It seems to me that the following:

```
$ sed 's/\r$//' file.txt | sponge > file.txt
```

with sponge from [moreutils](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) results in an empty `file.txt`, whether or not `file.txt` initially contains text. I don't believe the sed filter is special here, it just happens to be what I was using when I encountered the issue.

Is this reproducible on your machine? Why isn't `sponge` "soaking" up the output from sed before the shell opens `file.txt` for writing?

Comment: You use `sponge` wrong. Its syntax is `sponge file`.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to @Cyrus, sponge is meant to take the name of a file to output to rather than outputting to stdout.